# database field with type timestamp is not updating

Tags: database, codeigniter

> Duplicate of [database timestamp value is not
>   updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953065/database-timestamp-value-is-not-updating)

I have a variable which contains the date and time in 0000-00-00 00:00:00 format but when i put this variable in database field with type timestamp .. it is still 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: @mehwish can u pls provide some more details..

Comment: i have a variable in which i am taking date and time in 0000-00-00 00:00:00 format from a calender. now i have to put this variable into a database table's field whose type is timestamp. let us suppose the variable contains 2011:08-08 00:01:01 so this time and dae should be inserted into the table but it is not

Comment: can you post some code that illustrates exactly what you're doing?

Comment: $validtill=$this->input->post("validtill");
 $user_poll_query=array(
                                    'description'=>$poll_query,
                                         'creator_id'=>$user_id,
                                      'Valid_till'=>$validtill
                                   );
             $this->db->insert('sl_polls',$user_poll_query);

Comment: Duplicate of [database timestamp value is not updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953065/database-timestamp-value-is-not-updating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the right format of the datetime. Mysql default datetime format is YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s. But, it seems that you are trying to insert the datetime value with the format of (YYYY:MM-DD H:i:s). It does not allow to insert the datetime value, so the inserted value becomes 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Try by changing your calendar format to (YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s). I assume that you are using datatime datatype for the Valid_till column. Click the below to know more about mysql data structure.

[Mysql Date format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)